# Why does my implementation of Haskell snd not compile in Scala?

Tags: scala, tuples, arity

I defined the following function along the lines of Haskell [snd](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=snd)

```
def snd[T](pair: (_, T)): T = pair._2
```

Trying to use it with a `List[ListNode[T]]` doesn't compile. Why not?

```
list
  .reduceOption(snd)
```

where:

```
case class ListNode[T](data: T, var next: Option[ListNode[T]])(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]) extends Ordered[ListNode[T]] {...}
```

Error:

```
Type mismatch, expected: (NonInferedA1, NonInferedA1) => NonInferedA1, actual Tuple2[_, Nothing] => Nothing
```

Comment: What is `Node`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Updated question, not sure why'd it matter though.

Comment: I think it expects a function with two parameters, not one that’s a pair?

Comment: Indeed, the definition of `ListNode` doesn't matter much... You could have constructed `List.empty[Int]`, and thereby omit any mention of `Node` or `NodeList`... Anyway: `reduceOption` needs a two-argument function. `snd` takes only one argument.

Comment: It works as expected with `def twoArgSnd[T](a: Any, b: T): T = b` and `reduceOption(twoArgSnd[Int])`.

Comment: Right, defining `def snd[T](a: _, b: T): T = b` works, If one of you care to post an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Thanks. A question with an accepted answer also ranks higher in searches, so helpful to others later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods `reduce` and `reduceOption` require functions with arity `2`, not unary functions that take a tuple.

There is a difference between

```
Function1[(X, Y), Z]
```

and

```
Function2[X, Y, Z]
```

The first one is unary and takes a tuple, the second one is binary. Same holds for methods and their eta-expansions.

This here works as expected:

```
def twoArgSnd[T](a: Any, b: T): T = b 

list.reduceOption(twoArgSnd[Int])
```

---

Also related:

1. [Why is `scala.collection.immutable.List[Object]` not `GenTraversableOnce[?]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253836/why-is-scala-collection-immutable-listobject-not-gentraversableonce/52253961#52253961)

Comment: It works as expected... [if you expect it to work the way it actually works](https://books.google.com/books?id=4K82efXzn10C&pg=PA72#v=onepage&q&f=false).